# Getting contents of Tornado's xsrf_form_html() function outside of a template

Tags: python, tornado

I'm using Tornado for a python application, I want to put the value of xsrf_form_html() in my forms but I'm using Mustache to render templates instead of the standard Tornado template system. Is there any way to get that value to a variable? I did try

```
xsrfform = xsrf_form_html()
```

but that didn't work. Is it under some special class name?
-Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how mustache works, but every RequestHandler has that method, so you must pass it to the template like any other value.